# Data Sheets or Power Output ratings for Cisco Power Supplies

Tags: current, maximum-ratings

I have 2 used Cisco power supply units that I would like to re-purpose into bench power supplies. The first is a Astec AA20270, Cisco part # 34-0850-01. The second is a Computer Products NFN40-7632E, Cisco part # 34-0625-02. I can not find any data sheets for these 2 supplies. I need to find out the maximum current draw they can handle first. I used a meter and determined that the voltage outputs on both supplies are the same, with +12v, 5v, and -12v.  Thanks for any help on how to locate this information or figuring it out.

Comment: First, welcome to EE.SE!  Usually a power supply's label will show the input and output specs; neither of these are labelled?

Comment: No, they just have the Cisco Part labels. Some kind of a ratings label would of made this easy . . .  lol